# Analytics event tracking works on console but not on WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, analytics, tracking

I'm trying to track a form success message on Wordpress so I created the code below to a plugin that allows custom JS. My problem is that it works when pasted directly on the console, but when I add it to the site it won't work. I can see the code on the page source but it doesn't fire.

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
                if(jQuery('.alert-success').text().length > 0){
                ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit');
            }
            });
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the code, and you're not getting console errors, it means that your if statement is returning false - in this case that means `.alert-success` doesn't have any inner text when the document loads, which is when this is fired.

If `.alert-success` changes based on an event you're trying to track, this code won't detect it, because it's not "live"m it fires once when the pages loads and that's it. You'll need to instead bind it to an event handler or mutation event such as

```
$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".alert-success", function() {
    if($('.alert-success').text().length > 0){
        ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit');
    }
});
```

Though, ideally you'd have that code fire on the same event handler you're trying to track (form submit, ajax request completed, etc.)

Comment: Hi Xhynk. Thank you for the reply. You are right about .alert-sucess and the success message text detection when the page is not reloded. I tried your code but it didn't work. In wordpress we should use "jQuery" instead of "$" and the plugin I use  ask that if we use jQuery we should wrap our code with: jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    // Code here 
});

Comment: Yes I understand but that's actually a misconception. The fact you have `($)` in your document ready function means you're giving jQuery an alias of `$` and it's perfectly fine to use. I meant to put the code I gave you INSIDE your ready function. Doesn't not work if it's in there?